# What is wrong with this manifest/jar command?

Tags: java, jar, manifest, execution

I have a test java file that compiles and that I have packaged into a jar file. I don't understand why the conventional java execution command:

```
java -jar My_Class.jar
```

does not work but this form of command is successful:

```
java -cp My_Class.jar My_Class
```

**Details**

This is the My_Class.java file. I actually found it on another stackoverflow page, I'm sorry, I can't find the link any more. The only function is to print the phrase "This is an inner class" and to demonstrate the problem. It's useful because this problem only seems to occur with some mix of inner classes:

```
class Outer_Demo {
   int num;

   // inner class
   private class Inner_Demo {
      public void print() {
         System.out.println("This is an inner class");
      }
   }

   // Accessing he inner class from the method within
   void display_Inner() {
      Inner_Demo inner = new Inner_Demo();
      inner.print();
   }
}

public class My_Class {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // Instantiating the outer class 
      Outer_Demo outer = new Outer_Demo();

      // Accessing the display_Inner() method.
      outer.display_Inner();
   }
}
```

Here is my **manifest** file content:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.0 (author)
Main-Class: My_Class Outer_Demo Outer_Demo\$1 Outer_Demo\$Inner_Demo
```

There is a trailing newline in the file, in case anyone asks.

Here is my **jar** command:

```
jar cvfm My_Class.jar My_Class-manifest.txt My_Class.class Outer_Demo.class Outer_Demo\$1.class Outer_Demo\$Inner_Demo.class
```

**Results**

The jar command appears to work, it makes My_Class.jar which contains the four classes:

Outer_Demo$1.class

Outer_Demo$Inner_Demo.class

Outer_Demo.class

My_Class.class

However the execution fails when I use the first command I mentioned at the top of the question with the error message

```
Error: Could not find or load main class My_Class Outer_Demo Outer_Demo\$1 Outer_Demo\$Inner_Demo
```

Comment: The main class entry is supposed to contain the name of **THE** main class. Not the name of all the classes in the jar file. The main class is the one containing the main method, i.e. My_Class.

Comment: `Main-Class: My_Class Outer_Demo Outer_Demo\$1 Outer_Demo\$Inner_Demo` This is wrong, it should contain only the main class name.

Comment: Great, thankyou, that looks like a good step forward. Am I missing a line then? Where should I define all the other inner classes?

Comment: You shouldn't. Why do you think you should? They are in the jar file. All Java needs to know when passing the -jar option is which of the many classes in the jar is the main one.

Comment: @JBNizet,  sorry I should have been clearer who I was responding to. In your first comment you begin "The main class entry ...". Were you referring to the manifest file or the jar file?

Comment: No. Your command creates a jar file. And this jar file (which is basically just a zip file) contains all the class files. When executing java -jar foo.jar, you're telling Java to execute the main class referenced by the Main-Class entry of the manifest contained in foo.jar, and to find all the classes it needs to find inside foo.jar (and in other jar filesreferenced by the Class-Path manifest entry).

Comment: I was referring to the manifest Main-Class entry.

Comment: OK thanks, that makes sense now, I'll try it later